# Facebook Chat API - Is Chat possible with 2 unknown users?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, chat, facebook-chat

I was wondering:

1. Is it possible to chat with a friend who is not in our friend list through the API?
2. Can 2 Unknown users use the Facebook Chat API to communicate? Is it possible anyhow (using PHP or JS?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only way to do this would be through the use of the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) where you could specify the UID of the non-friend in the `&to=` parameter. There is no API method publicly available for sending messages to non-friends.